# SQL - Perform SELECT with condition from another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have four tables: `user`, `game`, `user_games_joined`, and `user_rating`.

A user may give a 'rating' for another user, but ONLY if they have played a game with that user (i.e. the `user_games_joined` table contains rows for each user for the same game) **since the last time they gave a rating for that user**.

I'm trying to build a single SELECT statement that will tell us if a user is currently allowed to give a rating for another particular user.  Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM user_games_joined from_joined
LEFT JOIN game ON from_joined.game_uuid = game.uuid
INNER JOIN user_games_joined to_joined ON from_joined.game_uuid = to_joined.game_uuid
WHERE from_joined.user_uuid = [USER_GIVING_RATING_UUID]
AND to_joined.user_uuid = [USER_RECEIVING_RATING_UUID]
AND game.date > [DATE_OF_MOST_RECENT_RATING];
```

If this statement returns `0`, the final answer is **false**; else **true** (at least one game has been played between the two users since the last rating was given).  The problem is that [DATE_OF_MOST_RECENT_RATING] is unknown: it must be determined from the `user_rating` table.  Here's how we might query that piece of information:

```
SELECT date from user_rating
WHERE to_user_uuid = [USER_RECEIVING_RATING_UUID]
AND from_user_uuid = [USER_GIVING_RATING_UUID]
ORDER BY date DESC LIMIT 1;
```

So of course I could accomplish this task with two separate queries, but for obvious reasons I'd like to combine it into a single statement.  Can somebody help me out with this?  Thanks!

**EDIT:** For bonus points, can somebody come up with a way to perform this check during an INSERT into the `user_rating` table as well, so the validation doesn't need to occur as a separate query before the INSERT?

Comment: I removed the Oracle tag because the syntax suggests MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather complicated set of joins with some aggregation:

```
select (case when coalesce(max(ur.rating_date), max(g.date)) <= max(g.date) then 'Go and Rate'
             else 'No, no, no.  Go and play'
        end)
from user_game g join
     user_games_joined ufrom 
     on ufrom.game_uuid = g.uuid and
        ufrom.user_uuid = g.from_user_uuid join
     user_games_joined uto
     on uto.game_uuid = g.uuid and
        uto.user_uuid = g.to_user_uuid left join
     user_rating ur join
     on ur.from_user_uuid = ufrom.user_uuid and
        ur.to_user_uuid = uto.user_uid
where to_user_uuid = [USER_RECEIVING_RATING_UUID] and
      from_user_uuid = [USER_GIVING_RATING_UUID];
```

For your purposes, a better `select` is:

```
select (max(ur.rating_date) < max(g.date))
```

Comment: Should there be a `join` after `from user_rating ur` (line 4)? And should `on from.game_uuid` be `on ufrom.game_uuid` (line 11)?

Comment: It's not quite working, but I can't seem to figure out why. I made the two changes from my previous comment, assuming that's what you meant originally, but it returns 'no' even though I've confirmed that the data should return 'yes'.

Comment: @hundley . . . I had the joins all wrong.  I think they are better now.

Comment: I think we're close. The issue here is that `game` does not have `from_user_uuid` or `to_user_uuid` columns - only a rating does. The only applicable columns from `game` are `uuid` and `date`; the `user_games_joined` table keeps track of which users have joined which games. It also looks like there's an extra JOIN at the end of line 11, I think.

Answer (score 0):

Writing a generic query since I dont know which db you are using. I havent tested this either so might have some errors but you should get the gist of it from below. You might have to tweak your query for syntax and performance:

```
INSERT INTO user_rating
     SELECT new_rating FROM DUAL
            WHERE EXISTS (
                  SELECT 1 --selecting 1 IS FASTER THAN COUNT(*)
                       FROM user_games_joined from_joined
                           LEFT JOIN game 
                               ON from_joined.game_uuid = game.uuid
                           INNER JOIN user_games_joined to_joined 
                               ON from_joined.game_uuid = to_joined.game_uuid
                           INNER JOIN user_rating XX
                               ON XX.to_user_uuid = to_joined.user_uuid
                                  AND XX.from_user_uuid = from_joined.user_uuid
                                  AND Game.date > XX.date 
                       WHERE from_joined.user_uuid = [USER_GIVING_RATING_UUID]
                           AND to_joined.user_uuid = [USER_RECEIVING_RATING_UUID]
                           AND game.date > [DATE_OF_MOST_RECENT_RATING];
                         );
```